# Dataflow - Call external API with using private IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm getting an issue calling an external API from a Dataflow job.

Dataflow is running under project A, and the API is hosted in GKE in project B, with Istio. The service account used to run Dataflow has access to resources (like GCS) from project A and B.

The projects don't have a default network and in order to run Dataflow, I needed to set the flag --use_public_ips to false. With that, the job runs, but the API call isn't reaching the API controller and is returning the following error:

> I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException"

I tested the same job in a separate environment with a default network and with Dataflow and GKE hosted under the same project. In that environment using --use_public_ips=true, the API call works, and using --use_public_ips=false it doesn't.

My questions are:
1 - What does the --use_public_ips flag changes exactly in terms of external access to resources and how can we configure my services to work with that?
2 - Is there's a way to run Dataflow in a project without default network (subnetwork specified at runtime), and not use the --use_public_ips flag set to false.

Comment: Does your GKE cluster in project B expose a public IP?

Comment: Keep in mind that API calls to google servers do not require an external IP which is why calls to GCS will work. How is your API exposed in the cluster? How is the call made (by ip or FQDN)? Since you have 2 different projects and no external IPs, you need to make sure that the API call is targetting an internal IP and that there is a peering between the networks in the two projects